# "I wouldn't want to around the amount of people at that pool party even before the pandemic."

Tags: word-usage, will-would

First of all, I would like to know what differences do the use of won't and wouldn't make in any sentences, and what kind of meanings (wouldn’t) would conveys in the following sentence.

> I wouldn't want to around the amount of people at that pool party even before the pandemic.

Comment: Please provide your definitions of the words [*will*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will) and [*would*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would), and where you think there is confusion. I should also point out that the sentence itself needs to be changed in order to be grammatical.

Comment: I think you've omitted a verb in that sentence. Did you mean something like "I wouldn't want to *be* around the amount of people at that pool party even before the pandemic" or "I wouldn't want to *go* around the amount of people at that pool party even before the pandemic"?

Answer (score 1):

> I wouldn't want to ??? around the amount of people at that pool party even before the pandemic.

As others pointed out, there's a missing verb (which would go where I've placed the ???). It's ungrammatical without it, but it *would* be said in real English, if the missing infinitive verb were already understood. I'm guessing it's just a typo and the word *be* is missing; but the sentence would be okay if the preceding sentence had been something like "I don't want to hang out around a lot of people with the pandemic going on." The provided sentence would then sound fairly natural (even though it'd still be technically an incomplete sentence), and would be an explanation of the fact that the pandemic isn't even the only problem (which it is in any case).

While it's true that *would* is technically the past tense form of *will*, it is not being used here to express a past tense. It is being used here to express a hypothetical - that is, the speaker(/writer) is expressing what their desires would be (heh, there it is again) if you change the situation to something other than the situation that actually exists. When *would* is used in this sense, it's indicating a future or present activity (but not our actual present: some hypothetical, alternative present). If we then want to talk about a hypothetical past event, we use "would not have" (that is, we add a present perfect tense for the primary verb). "I would not have come if I had known Sam was here."

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't normally means that something is habitual, saying, "I wouldn't do that" implies that you are viewing a situation from the other person's perspective, and advising that of you were in the same situation, you wouldn't make a particular choice. "I won't do that" refers to denying a particular task.

In some instances "wouldn't" and "won't" can be interchangeable, such as, "wouldn't/won't you do something" is simply asking somebody to do something, it doesn't matter.

Directly in the definition of the words, "won't" is conjoined from "will not" and "wouldn't' is conjoined from "would not". In these instances, "would" is indefinite while "will" is definite.

Comment: "would" is the future tense of "will"...?

Comment: Something like that

Comment: It's more in the sense of indefinite (would) vs definite (will) I'll make an edit

Comment: @RamPillai the following “*I **wouldn't** do that **if** I were you*” is a conditional sentence referring to an *unreal* present. It's impossible for the speaker to be also the listener but *if he/she were*, they would not do that action. Similarly the original sentence is talking about an unreal event, the speaker is currently *not* in that situation, and they are saying they **wouldn't want to be** either.

Comment: Agree to your views.

Answer (score 0):

**Wouldn't** is *would not*, its past tense. **Won't** is *will not*, its future tense. Like I won't do it tomorrow, and I wouldn't have read it anyways as examples.
They are considered to be informal as well.

Answer (score -1):

//I wouldn't want to around the amount of people at that pool party even before the pandemic.// Yes, it shows futurity, but one can also say, "I won't want to..." which is future too. There are confusions and different views on the use of will and would, but I feel 'wouldn't is a little more polite and modest compared to the firm/ definitive "won't".  Change from won't to wouldn't may also happen while using reported speech.